# Negation of “tener que”

Tags: expresiones, significado, definiciones

I'd like to clarify the meaning of the structure *no tener que + verb*.

Suppose I say the following:

> No tengo que salir.

Which one of the following does the statement above mean?

> 1. I don't have to leave.
> 2. I have to not leave.

In the first situation, I am expressing that I don't have to leave meaning that I can stay if I wanted to, whereas in the second situation I am expressing that I have to stay.

In general, my question is which part gets negated, the "have to" or the "verb" that comes after?

Thanks.

Comment: "No tengo que salir" = "I don't have to leave".  The (2) would be "No puedo salir" meaning "i have to stay" because in Spanish it would be super weird to say "tengo que NO salir".

Comment: It would be super weird to say ‘I have to not leave’ in English too.

Comment: Yes, I agree that it would weird to say that in English.

Comment: As a rule of thumb, you can translate "to have to" as *tener que* and "to must" as "deber"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"No tengo que salir" is ambiguous in Spanish.

It may mean lack of necessity or lack of obligation (I'd venture to say this meaning is more usual):

- I don't have/need to leave.

or negative obligation or prohibition:

- I mustn't leave.

Context will define the correct meaning:

> **Por suerte** no tengo que salir. (Lack of obligation/necessity)
>
> No tengo que salir **bajo ningún concepto**. (Prohibition)

For the prohibition meaning, other forms will be more usual:

- No debo salir.
- Está prohibido que salga.
- No me permiten salir.
- Tengo prohibido salir.
- No puedo salir. (Where "no puedo" means "I'm not allowed to". This sentence is also ambiguous, allowing for an incapacity meaning: "I'm unable to".)

Answer (score 2):

Beginners will do fine learning the following two structures as negations of "Tengo que salir":

> No [me] hace falta salir

This means *I don't have to leave* or *There's no need to leave*.

> No hay que salir

This means *I must not leave* or *I better not leave.*